# Creating layout & logic AutoCAD plugin dialog

Tags: c#, .net, dll, autocad, objectarx

I am brand new to AutoCAD plugin development. I'm trying to create a plugin that loads as an entire main menu option inside of AutoCAD (let's call this menu the "`Fizzbuzz`" menu, and when the user selects one of the menu items (say, `Fizzbuzz >> Foobar`) I want a simple dialog/window to show up on screen in the top-left corner of AutoCAD.

I'm trying to figure out where the presentation/layout logic for this dialog/popup window needs to go (what file does it live in and how do I create/edit it?), and just as importantly: where the event-driven GUI logic needs to go (again: what file do I edit and in what language?). By "*GUI logic*" I mean: let's say there's a checkbox or button inside my dialog... when the user clicks/interacts with these UI components, I need custom logic to execute.

What files house this type of presentation/GUI logic for new AutoCAD plugins and how I create/edit them?

Comment: Look into WPF MVVM. AutoCAD palettes are an easy way to get a modeless UI, as is the Ribbon - if you don't hate it. Read the [topic wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info) for more resources.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a palette hosting a winform control this way:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Windows;

namespace AMU.AutoCAD.BlockTool
{
  public class MyPalette : IExtensionApplication
  {

  private PaletteSet palette;
  private Control paletteControl;

  public void Initialize()
  {
    //This is called when AutoCAD loads your assembly
    this.palette = new PaletteSet("Name")
    {
      TitleBarLocation = PaletteSetTitleBarLocation.Left,
      Style = PaletteSetStyles.Snappable //Your Styles
    };
    this.paletteControl = new Control(); //Instance of your Control that will be visible in AutoCAD
    this.palette.Add("HEADER", this.paletteControl);
    this.palette.Visible = true;

  }

  public void Terminate()
  {
    //cleanup
    this.palette.Dispose();
    this.paletteControl.Dispose();
  }
}
}
```

By providing a class implementing the IExtensionApplication you can execute custom code on loading a dll, without explicitly call a method. You now can create a so called PaletteSet and add a Winform or WPF Control to it.